# How do I prevent code duplication when defining multiple methods with the same name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, overloading, code-duplication

I recently discovered that you can define multiple methods with the same name as long as their arguments differ (I believe it's called method overloading). So for example, in a script I have a method called `getDate(int date)` and another called `getDate()`. The only differences between these methods is that the one that doesn't accept an argument uses a static integer defined in the class instead of the `date` argument.

I've used this logic for at least 5 different methods in the class, however it seems very messy to be duplicating code like this. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Please show us the code you're asking about.  Descriptions of code aren't that useful as they leave too much to the imagination and tend to be incomplete or inaccurate.

Comment: How about `public DateTime getDate() { return getDate(staticInt); }`? This would reuse the overload with the parameter by calling it, instead of copying the code. In any case, you should probably post your code so that we can see exactly what we're dealing with here, the devil is in the details and all that.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Man that's so simple and exactly what I need! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, its best to have one function that does the meat of what you're trying to achieve, while others invoke that function (or each other) to avoid duplicating actual logic.

I'll use your example:

```
Date GetDate(int date) {
    // -- do whatever you do here
    return DoAThing(date);
}

Date GetDate() {
    return GetDate(staticVar);
}
```

This way, if you want to change how you get a date, you won't have to change your code in multiple places, and when you modify `GetDate(int date)`, your other functions that invoke it will simply follow suit.

Comment: Oops. I didn't see that @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen basically already answered this since it was in a comment. But we are basically saying the same thing :)

Answer (score -1):

Just call the methods as needed e.g.

```
//To Get the Date normally
DateTime date = getDate();
//Otherwise
date = getDate(1, DateTime.Today);
```

You should not have a problem calling them. They should be overloaded correctly by unity because I checked it with my editor.

Comment: This is not the asker's problem.